# Resetting admin password which is tied to an Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id, password

An employee recently got a new company mac, then left the company. We've reset plenty of mac passwords in the past by using recovery mode > utilities > terminal > 'resetpassword' > select admin > type in new password.

Instead now, it asks for an Apple ID login. We don't know the login.

Is there any other way to reset this password?

Comment: Is there any data on it? Is there a back-up to that data? A back-up policy? Completely wiping / fresh install may be the quickest solution...

Comment: @SolarMike Unless it also has a firmware password, in which case you may need to provide proof of ownership and get help from Apple.

Comment: Yes there is a data on it. It's a clients laptop, we do have a file sync software which is for company data but some times people store data outside of this. They're trying to get the password from them now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's locked by an AppleId, the only chance you have is to contact the owner of the AppleID or contacting Apple support for companies.

Comment: Thanks, We've come to the same conclusion now as it seems the drive is encrypted with File Vault.

Comment: Please mark my answer as solution.

Comment: Yes I always mark answers, it just has a long delay before I can.

Comment: We've reset the apple ID but the laptop says it's incorrect. I suspect it can't be reset.